# GCP Cloud Endpoints REST <> gRPC conversion not including all fields

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc-go

So I have a Go API that's calling another service, and setting up the response.

```
func (s *Server) GetCycle(ctx context.Context, req *pb.GetCycleRequest) (*pb.GetCycleResponse, error) {
    // Cycle request for Wave service
    waveReq := &wavepb.GetCycleRequest{
        Id:   req.UserId,
        Date: req.Date,
    }

    waveResp, err := s.WaveServiceClient.GetCycle(ctx, waveReq)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to get cycle: %w", err)
    }

    resp := &pb.GetCycleResponse{
        Cycle: &pb.Cycle{
            Id:             waveResp.Cycle.Id,
            CyclePhase:     pb.CyclePhase(waveResp.Cycle.GetCyclePhase()),
            NextCycleStart: waveResp.Cycle.GetNextCycleStart(),
            PeriodDuration: waveResp.Cycle.GetPeriodDuration(),
            PhaseLocation:  waveResp.Cycle.GetPhaseLocation(),
        },
    }
    log.Printf("GetCycle response: %v - Cycle Phase %v/%v - Phase Location %v/%v", resp, waveResp.Cycle.CyclePhase, resp.Cycle.CyclePhase, waveResp.Cycle.PhaseLocation, resp.Cycle.PhaseLocation)
    return resp, nil
}
```

The print line outputs the following

```
GetCycle response: cycle:{id:"fbd97c9d-3744-4cfc-9d2c-ca46f2b496d8" nextCycleStart:{seconds:1695081600} periodDuration:7} - Cycle Phase PHASE_1/PHASE_1 - Phase Location 0/0
```

For some reason even though `CyclePhase` and `PhaseLocation` are not nil, they are not being included in the output json, and I can't see why.

Here's the protobuf

```
message GetCycleRequest {
  google.protobuf.Timestamp date = 1;
  string userId = 2;
}

message Cycle {
  string id = 1;
  CyclePhase cyclePhase = 2;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp nextCycleStart = 3;
  int32 periodDuration = 4;
  double phaseLocation = 5;
}

message GetCycleResponse {
  Cycle cycle = 1;
  string message = 2;
}

enum CyclePhase {
  PHASE_1 = 0;
  PHASE_2 = 1;
  PHASE_3 = 2;
  PHASE_4 = 3;
  PHASE_5 = 4;
  PHASE_NA = 5;
}
```

UPDATE:

So it seems when `phaseLocation` is 0 (as it should have been) it gets omitted. Today the value is non-zero and it's showing through. Hard coding `cyclePhase` to be `PHASE_2` also allows it to come through the json.

Comment: Could you please provide the server implementation if you have it?

Comment: So there is no Server implementation? It's routed to the function from the protobuf.

Comment: I think I've found more hints, will update

Comment: What does `pb.GetCycleResponse` look like? Seems like an `omitempty` annotation is present on the struct and when you serialize it to JSON, that tells the encoder to not include that value if it's "empty". In the case of `int`, "empty" means the value is 0.

I'm almost certain this is the case. `omitempty` is hard-coded in [protoc-gen-go](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/84668698ea25b64748563aa20726db66a6b8d299/protoc-gen-go/generator/generator.go#L2243)

Comment: @PapaPete That is what's happening, but I have no clue how to stop it from generating that.

Comment: Instead of returning `pb.GetCycleResponse`, define your own type and create that type from the `pb.GetCycleResponse`, return THAT from your endpoint.